# Shift + 2 = @ in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

My OS is Win7.

I thnik I have accidentally hit some kind of key combination that changed my keyboard layout so that now altgr+v doesn't do anything and shif+2 makes @. Some other keys are messed up too.

What did I do and how do I revert it?

P.S. It seems to be the Mac keyboard layout, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: Sounds like a keyboard layout thing. Check your Region and Language settings in control panel, look under Keyboard and Languages tab. However, I fail to see how this is a programming question... EDIT: You might need to turn on "small icons" to see the category in control panel.

Comment: It's limited only to Eclipse, everywhere else is fine. It's not really programming question, but people have been discussing various Eclipse capabilites here...

Comment: Ah. Well, I don't have an installation of Eclipse handy at the moment... I've worked with multiple languages installed before, I believe the keyboard shortcut in Windows is ALT+SHIFT. EDIT: Also check the language bar. Each process has its own language settings, so it would make sense if you accidentally ALT+SHIFTed Eclipse into another language.